# REGEXP_SUBSTR return all matches (mariaDB)

Tags: mariadb, regexp-substr

I need to get all the matches of a regular expression in a text field in a **MariaDB** table. As far as I know **REGEXP_SUBSTR** is the way to go to get the value of the match of a regular expression in a text field, but it always returns after the first match and I would like to get **all matches**.

**Is there any way to do this in MariaDB?**

An example of the content of the text field would be:

```
@Generation {
// 1
True =>
    `CP?:24658` <= `CPV?:24658=57186`;
//`CP?23432:24658` <= `CPV?:24658=57186`

// 2
`CP?:24658` <> `CPV?:24658=57178` =>
    `CP?:24656` <> `CPV?:24656=57169`;
```

And the select expression that I'm using right now is:

> select REGEXP_SUBSTR(textfield,'`CP\\?(?:\\d*:)*24658`') as my_match 
>   from table
>   where id = 1243;

Which at the moment returns just the first match:

- `CP?:24658`

And I would like it to return all matches:

- `CP?:24658`
- `CP?23432:24658`
- `CP?:24658`

Comment: There would need to a function which can return something like an array of results, and I don't know if MariaDB has anything like that.  But, do you have to do this work inside the database in the first place?

Comment: Yup it is the fastest way since I have to get all the matches of potentially thousands of records of the database to process them.

Answer (score 2):

1. Use just `REGEXP` to find the interesting rows.  Put those into a temp table
2. Repeatedly process the temp table -- but remove the `SUBSTR` as you use it.

What will you be doing with each substr?  Maybe that will help us devise a better approach.